# CSS max of width percentage, length of element

Tags: html, css

I’m looking for a way to set the width of an element to the greater of the percentage given or the length of the text of the element.  I would also like this to stay on one line if possible (up to 100% of the width of the parent).  In the example below, the first item would have a yellow background to 40% of the width.  The third item would rely upon the length of the text to generate a yellow background. Thank you for your help!

```css
.section_header {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="section_header"> Loren Ipsum </h2>
<h2 class="section_header"> Loren Ipsum Loren Ipsum </h2>
<h2 class="section_header"> Loren Ipsum Loren Ipsum Loren Ipsum </h2>
```

Comment: min-width won't do, h2 = block level element https://jsfiddle.net/Lrf5zqst/

Comment: Thank you VPx... That worked.